# How to position same number of divs each row?

Tags: html, css

I would like to have 3 divs in the same row and the next 3 in the next row. How can I do that?

This is what I have so far:

```css
.wrapper {
  float: left;
}

.item {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"> test </div>
  <div class="item"> test </div>
  <div class="item"> test </div>
  <div class="item"> test </div>
  <div class="item"> test </div>
  <div class="item"> test </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```css
body {margin: 0}

.wrapper {
  column-count: 3; /* three columns/divs per row */
  column-gap: 0; /* if you want to add some gaps between items */
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid-column;
}

.wrapper > .item {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"> test </div>
  <div class="item"> test </div>
  <div class="item"> test </div>
  <div class="item"> test </div>
  <div class="item"> test </div>
  <div class="item"> test </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should check out Flexbox. You just set `display: flex` to the wrapper and you'll see how the children `div` start positioning themselves. There's tons of documentation here in Stackoverflow. Just take a look and see how easy It ends up being. Hope It helped!